# Adding data validation (drop down) list to a range of cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large range ("C2:C100") to add a drop down list to.

I've tried the following:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("c2:c100").Validation
.Add xlValidateList, xlValidAlertStop, xlBetween, "=Sheet3!a2:a5"
.InCellDropdown = True
End With
```

But that only worked for cell C2. So then I tried:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("c2:c100")
    With .Validation
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Sheet3!a2:a5"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End With
```

And have continued to get an error with line ".Add Type..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you've removed any Validation from all cells before adding Validation to the range. Running .Delete before .Add will produce no error if none exists and remove any that does exist.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("c2:c100").Validation
    .Delete
    .add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
         Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Sheet3!$A$2:$A$5"
    .InCellDropdown = True
End With
```

I prefer using named parameters; especially when those parameters are optional.

You need to make the list range reference absolute or the list becomes relative to the cell position. e.g. C3 would be Sheet3!A3:A6, C4 would be Sheet3!A4:A7, etc.